# Ubuntu 18.04 Slow boot due to snapd

Tags: boot, 18.04, startup, snap

After upgrading from 17.04 to 18.04 I found bootup to be a little slow. After running `systemd-analyze blame` I get the following output

```
     38.090s snapd.seeded.service
     36.432s snapd.service
      6.485s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      2.462s keyboard-setup.service
      1.784s vmware.service
      1.614s apt-daily.service
      1.572s ufw.service
      1.536s apt-daily-upgrade.service
      1.203s dev-sda1.device
       482ms upower.service
       461ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       443ms networkd-dispatcher.service
       423ms NetworkManager.service
       399ms systemd-logind.service
       349ms vmware-USBArbitrator.service
       318ms swapfile.swap
       308ms dnsmasq.service
       305ms udisks2.service
       290ms systemd-rfkill.service
       280ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       249ms ModemManager.service
       237ms systemd-resolved.service
       232ms systemd-timesyncd.service
```

What can I do to reduce the bootup time, specifically these snapped services?

Comment: I'd make sure fully updated (`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`) Then purge snapd (`sudo apt purge snapd`) After that open Software & Updates > Developer options > enable the proposed repo. Then update sources & install snapd. (`sudo apt update && sudo apt install snapd`). After it's installed again open Software & Updates & disable the proposed repo, update sources.

Comment: Thanks @doug. The update definitely helped a reducing the startup time to 17 seconds. But it still takes much longer than the 6 seconds for the second process.

Comment: Here all the snapd stuff in systemd-analyze blame  is completely done by 202ms (i.e snapd.service) , the snapd.seeded.service at 8ms. So NetworkManager-wait-online.service is top shown (at about 6 sec.

Comment: What happens if you install a snap? (assuming you don't have any installed?

Comment: HI doug, I checked again and snapd was done at >200ms. Thanks, I'm not sure if it was the purge or a recent update but network is now theslowest process. Thanks.  I did previously try installing hello world snapd package but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this today with 18.04 too (no upgrade, was fine before today), I've found that moving my mouse/swiping my trackpad constantly on the loading screen speeds loading up by a lot for this issue, though I am unsure why. It goes from >4 min to less than 1 min.

Comment: 2022... happened to me today.. I just Clonezilla'd back to last wee,k, the whole partition, but your answer reminds me of Truecrypt or Veracrypt when you make an encrypted container or volume, you need to 'seed' the random number by moving the mouse, as randomly as possible, the longer time the better. oh well :-\